# Compile Qt 5.2 application with the compiler MSVC2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, qt

I have developed an application using Qt 5.2 which has be to be compiled in Visual studio 2008. But i found on the following link that the oldest MSVC compiler that can be used with Qt5 is MSVC2010.

[Link](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Framework/Supported-Platforms/)

Is it possible to compile Qt 5.2 application with MSVC 2008 ?

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: Do it at your own discretion. The fact that msvc2008 is missing from Qt list means they didn't bother to maintain for this compiler. Just try to compile from source and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You will need one of three solutions:

1) Drop MS2008 and use a modern compiler

2) Use an older Qt that supports VS2008 (some Qt4 version)

3) Compile Qt5 with old compiler and hope the best

I would try to do 1) even if it means some effort. You should always try to stay up to date (and the longer you wait the more difficult it gets). If this isn't possible I would probably try 2) since it gives you an oudated but at least stable Qt. 3) is the worst solution at my opionion since anything could happen... without good chances to cleanly solve appearing compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

As the http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/ (but also your link) shows there is no official package for Qt 5.2 with MSVC2008. However, this does not mean you should not try to compile it.

Just download the source from http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/single/ and try to compile it. I see in the `mkspec` directory an entry for `win32-msvc2008` so in theory it should work, however I cannot guarantee that it will compile flawlessly.

But I am very curious how did you manage to

> developed an application using Qt 5.2 which has be to be compiled in Visual studio 2008

Maybe you should upgrade your compiler to get the full benefits that come with it.

Comment: The standard in my company for the moment is VS 2008, so they said they cannot upgrade to VS 2010 for the moment. either downgrade to Qt 4.7 or try to compile it with VS 2008.

In the past, i had issues porting from Qt 4 to Qt 5. So i developed the application using MinGW compiler without having any idea that i shall have to compile it using VS 2008 as well.

Comment: What is this standard for?